# How to draw the sum of two CDF in R

Tags: r, plot

I try to plot a linear combination of the CDF of standard normal distribution `1-Phi(2-x)+Phi(-2-x)`, where `Phi` is the CDF of standard normal distribution. I know how to draw one, such as `Phi(2-x)` and I also put the code as below. But how to draw the sum of two CDF in R or Python?

My code is

```
m <- 0
s <- 1
z <- pnorm(x,mean=m,sd=s)
plot(2-x, z,type="l",col="blue",lwd=2,las=1, xlab="X")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curve(-pnorm(2 - x) + pnorm(-2 - x), from = -10, to = 10)
```

[image]

`pnorm` is the cumulative distribution function. You can use `+` for addition, just like normal. At the `?pnorm` help page you can see that the defaults are `mean = 0` and `sd = 1`, so you don't need to specify them.

`curve` is a handy shortcut, but you could do a little bit more work to use `plot` as you did in the question:

n = 500
x = seq(-5, 5, length.out = n)
plot(x, -pnorm(2 - x) + pnorm(-2 - x),
type="l",col="blue",lwd=2,las=1, xlab="X")

[image]

Comment: So `1-Phi(2-x)+Phi(-2-x)` is `curve(1-pnorm(2 - x) + pnorm(-2 - x), from = -10, to = 10)`? Just add `1` in the `curve`? Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, missed the 1, sorry.

Comment: That's fine. Thanks a lot!